# Can I get away with not mocking all methods in an interface in C++ when using googlemock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

I am using Google Mock 1.6 RC and am trying to Mock a `COM Interface`. There are close to 50 methods in the COM Interface some of which are inherited from base interfaces. When I create a mock `struct` that inherits from this interface and mock only the methods I am using, I get the `cannot instantiate abstract class` error.

I want to know if it is possible to do this in googlemock or not.

Comment: Not familiar with Google Mock, but usually such situations are handled with the help of an adapter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do. You have to overload all pure virtual methods from all interfaces (except for the constructor and destructor).

Comment: Can I use inheritance to create mock objects. For example an abstract class B inherits from an abstract class A, is it possible to create a MockB which inherits from MockA and each of the mock classes only mock the specific pure virtual methods in the corresponding classes

Comment: @rtdecl Yes, that you can do, but you can only instantiate the one with all pure virtual methods overloaded.

Comment: I tried creating a `MockIUnknown` inheriting from `IUnknown` and a `MockIDispatch` inheriting from `IDispatch` and `MockIUnknown`. `IUnknown` has 3 pure virtual methods which I have mocked in `MockIUnknown` and `IDispatch` has 4 additional pure virtual methods which I have mocked in `MockIDispatch`. I am able to create and instance of `MockIUnknown` but not of `MockIDispatch`, I get the 'cannot instantiate abstract class' error

Comment: @rtdecl That is really strange. Did you check the signature of methods in MockIDispatch? Maybe that is wrong. It is hard to tell without seeing a code (or a minimal example showing the problem).

Answer (score 2):

You have to override every method that has been declared as pure virtual in the classes you inherit from, directly or indirectly. There are two reasons not to want override them all:

1. There are too many of them and you have something better to do with your time than to go over them all.
2. Compiling a mock class with all of them mocked out is too slow and takes too much memory.

The fix for (1) is to use the `gmock_gen.py` script in Google Mock's `scripts` directory. It goes over the class definition and converts method declarations into the `MOCK_METHOD` statements. If you have problems with (2), you can replace the unnecessary `MOCK_METHOD` statements with stubs:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(f, bool(int i));
```

with

```
virtual bool f(int i) {
  thrown std::exception("The stub for f(int) has been invoked unexpectedly.");
}
```

Throwing an exception will alert you to a situation where a particular stub has been invoked, meaning you likely need to mock it instead.

Edit: If the original interfaces to mock are written using Microsoft's macros, [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/x04ueA0iQ9M/discussion) has a script posted that converts them to C++ acceptable to `gmock_gen.py`.

Comment: > Throwing an exception will alert you to a situation where a particular stub has been invoked, meaning you likely need to mock it instead.

You can also use a "strict" mock to check that only expected calls on the mock object are called: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure whether all methods should be covered in the mock class... In the gmock examples you can see that for example destructors are not mocked. Therefore I presume there is no need to mock the entire class.

Anyway, shouldn't you create mock class rather than mock struct?

However, there is a gmock_gen.py tool in scripts/generator that should do the hard work of mocking large classes for you.

Comment: `Destructor` need not be explicitly mocked because your class will have a default destructor. I am creating a mock `struct` because the com interface that I am trying to mock is a `struct`. I will try using that script and see if it helps reduce some work

Comment: I suppose you could hack the script so it works for structs as well. I have no idea how much work it could be though. Anyway, google mock documentation mentions nothing about mocking structs.

Comment: Mocking class is similar to mocking structs (http://crpcut.sourceforge.net/1.2.0/using-gmock.html). I am not sure how simple it would be to modify the script since i am not familiar with Python

Comment: As a last resort I would try to temporarily change your struct to class, run the script and then change all 'class' keywords to 'struct'. It is not a solution though.